# Vertically align text to fraction line in equation with nested fractions

Tags: math-mode, align, fractions, baseline

I am trying to get output that would look like this:

[image]

The MWE I attached works well for equations with non-nested fractions or without fractions.

The problem arises when I have equations with nested fractions. The text on the left is offset compared to the part of the equation before =. Is there a way to align "Calculation" with "ROIC Ticker" at their baseline?

[image]

```
\documentclass[fleqn, 10pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Source Sans Pro}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Asana Math}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{-\baselineskip}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.15\textwidth}
    \textbf{Calculation}\par
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.85\textwidth}
    \begin{align}
        ROIC \ Ticker = \frac{e^{(\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\ln{(1+Daily \ Ticker \ Contribution)}}}-1}{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}|Position \ Size \ (CPS)|}{n}} 
    \end{align}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For better kerning, one should use the italic text font for longer variable names, as the math font can look ugly, here with "T icker" for example (in your first image and in the answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) use `\setmathfont{Asana Math}`,  not `\setmainfont`.

2) Use `alignat`  rather than two minipages, which align the tops of the minipages, not the top of the first minipage with with the first fraction line of the second minipage.

```
\documentclass[fleqn, 10pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Source Sans Pro}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

    \begin{alignat}{2}
     & \textbf{Calculation} &\qquad \ ROIC \ Ticker & = \frac{e^{(\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\ln{(1+ Daily~Ticker~Contribution)}}}-1}{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lvert Position~Size~(CPS)\rvert}{n}}
    \end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, the \setmainfont{Asana Math} is more of a typo and me not paying attention to what I copy.

Comment: `\begin{alignat}{2}
& \textbf{Calculation} 
    &\qquad \mathit{ROIC~Ticker} 
        & = \frac{\mathrm{e}^{\,\sum_{i=1}^{n}
            \ln\left(1+\mathit{Daily~Ticker~Contribution}\right)}-1}
                 {\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lvert\mathit{Position~Size~(CPS)}\rvert}{n}}
    \end{alignat}`
 will look better :)

Comment: @Zarko: Thanks for the suggestion. Actually, I had thought of it, and found no real difference. What I would have liked was `\textit`, but the default text font is a sans font, so it didn't look very nice. Do you really see a difference in letterspacing with `\mathit`?

Comment: Differences are in letter spacing.  Many times I have the same dilemma, what is more correct: `\textit`  or `mathit`. I saw that some experts here prefer latter, i.e.: `mathit`, since it is name a variable.

Comment: @Zarko -- it's my understanding that the font used for `\mathit` is (at least using computer modern) the same as the font for `\textit`.  it is *not* the same as the italic used for math variables.  the reason for the different names is history; plain tex uses `\it` for both; latex has different ideas about how to do things.

Answer (score 1):

Put 'Calculation' inside the environment (which should be `equation` instead of `align` in my opinion since you're not aligning anything) without using `minipage`s. AND use `\setmathfont` instead of `\setmainfont` for math.

```
\documentclass[fleqn, 10pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Source Sans Pro}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{-\baselineskip}

\begin{equation}
    \textbf{Calculation}\qquad ROIC \ Ticker = \frac{e^{(\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\ln{(1+Daily \ Ticker \ Contribution)}}}-1}{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}|Position \ Size \ (CPS)|}{n}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the solid answer! I selected Bernard's answer just because it was first, both answers should do the trick for me.